# Creating a new sqlite table using a parameter in android by the user in realtime in Constructor

Tags: android, sqlite, parameters, constructor, sqliteopenhelper

I am working on an app where I want to offer the option of multiple users, each user would have his own sqlite table inside a single database, I tried looking for a way to make the table name as a parameter in SQLiteOpenHelper constructor but there is no such constructor allowed.

So my question is how to take a name given by the user and insert it as a table name inside the app and create the table inside an existing database at runtime.

Thanks

Comment: Why not make a users table with different identifiers for the users?

Comment: I want each user to have different set of columns, of course with the same column names for all users.

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to build your database. Can you explain why each user would need an own set of columns? How many columns will a user have, if one user would have all columns you plan to use?

Comment: each user will have his table because he will have a separate profile in the app and yes all users will use the exact same columns, 5 columns to be exact

Comment: But why not have one Table with user 1, user 2, user 3 etc. all can use the same columns but have different content in them. Have you ever worked with SQLite or SQL? Can you tell me what you want to save in the 5 different columns?

Comment: ok so maybe the disclaimer should have been that I am a newbie, secondly I want to store dates and date calculations

Comment: ok thanks now I got it.

Comment: then i would advise you to use an ORM system like ActiveAndroid https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid to build your SQLite tables. It's pretty simple for beginners to store data in SQLite tables. Just add compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT' to your build.gradle and read the doc on the github page. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I can accept your answers